# How to structure a website with both multiple countries and languages?

Tags: directory-structure

So I have an problem regarding logic I cant wrap my head around. I need to expand my application to two different countries which both have their own respective languages (some countries require up to 3 languages).

As it turns out `Country2` and `Country3` have totally different views and logic for some of the major components in my application which require different views and services regarding the business logic.

We have built modular system. And right now for `Country1` I have two languages, so under each module's resources i have `views/lang1` or `views/lang2` and based on middleware I show the correct language view.

Now how should I implement another country since most of the logic is different?

- Should I create modules for `Country1` and `Country2` under my main application, where it's own countries application is running ( meaning multiple views etc)? I believe this would make updating and maintaining the application harder among different developers from different countries.
- Should I create sub-directories under my TLD so `app.companyname.com/country1/en` where each application would have it own perspective git repository?
- Should I invest into buying domains for each `app.companyname.fr/en`
- Should I make subdomains for `fr.app.companyname.com`?

Which of these options would make the most sense in my case?

Comment: Anything wrong with using the way [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/) does it?

Comment: The thing is I cannot change language when I select specific language. For example I need country1 to have english language and french language with different content. Wikipedia has the same content in different languages if you know what I'm saying

Comment: I thought this was a structuring question. Now you're making it sound like you need an automated translator.

Comment: Are you saying what services your site provides change based on the language chosen?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let me try to explain a little better. We are expanding to another country which needs some sort of logic to display different views than our current application. All the translations are done already. So your example Wikipedia changes the language to Hispanic but the content doesn't change. I need the content to change based on region so in my case France has different content than Germany. France has French lang and english language while Germany has German and English language (all translations are done), but the content IS different

Comment: So theoretically you could have an English version for every country. Every country would have different content.

Comment: Yes and there's comes my question. How should i structure it? Because as I said, the countries need their own respective languages. Should the countries be put under subdirectory running its own application?

Comment: Consider how Dell does it: https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/ This way each country has a set of languages it can present its content in. Also consider remaining compatible with automated translators.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying here but in my case I need to have different language AND different content for each country.

Comment: Right but which dictates which? Are you going to have 3 languages for the whole site or are some of your countries bilingual and others trilingual?

Comment: Some countries are bilingual and trilingual. so companyname.eu/france/fr or companyname.eu/france/en and companyname.eu/spain/es or companyname.eu/spain/en so english language applies both BUT the content is different

Comment: If each country required different functionality/logic, then effectively each country needs its own webapp. Depending on programming language, framework and commonality between countries, you could try to create a set of shareable components and use those to statically or dynamically build the webapp for country X.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau thank you. that's what we decided to do eventually